# Misusing "which" as a conjunction

Tags: grammar, terminology

Does anybody have a name for this construction? To me it is non-grammatical.

> I hiked early this morning with my sister *which* I am not a morning person!

I hear this kind of thing quite a bit. It occurred to me that *which splice* might be a reasonable name; Google didn't back me up on that though.

The fundamental problem seems to be that *which*'s antecedent really has no grammatical connection to the latter half of the sentence while the speaker is clearly implying a link. (The linkage is destroyed by giving that secondary clause it's own new subject?)

Does this just amount to not recognizing that *which* is a pronoun and so trying to use it as a conjunction?

If anybody has insight on terminology or the root of the confusion I'd appreciate it.

**Edit**

*Which* seems to be functioning as an abbreviated stand-in for something more like *which is notable because*.

My perception is that it feels like a relative clause to the writer/speaker. The distance from the original subject *I* forces it to be restated for clarification. Yet even if we accept that as valid there's another concern over using *which* rather than *who*.

> I hiked early this morning with my sister *who* I am not a morning person! (X)

Would anybody argue in favor of that one?

**Edit 2**

This usage isn't limited to exclamation sentences yet I see a noteworthy twist in this example. A slightly awkward rephrasing alters the impact of the statement:

> I, not a morning person, hiked early this morning with my sister!

The *morning person* part is intensified by coming at the end and attaches semantically to the exclamatory mark. Had the spliced thoughts been separated by a full stop the meaning is probably nearly identical to what the writer wanted to convey and better reflected by the punctuation.

**Edit 3**

This is not an issue of ESL or dialect. Seeing it in print on Facebook is what prompted me to go ahead and post the question. I've heard it spoken many times by people I know well. This has nothing to do with auto-correction. I've thought about this many times before and investigated it myself.

Comment: "Though" would work.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree that it would. That's not what people say though.

Comment: People don't say "which" in that context.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree that they shouldn't say that, however, I do hear it regularly from a number of different people. This particular example comes straight from Facebook.

Comment: I doubt that you are hearing it from native English speakers.

Comment: They are all native speakers.

Comment: Must be some sort of dialect.  (Though do note that misuses of this sort are not at all unusual online, especially by folks who use auto-complete without checking the result.)

Comment: @shawnt00 are you _sure_ it's not dialect? It is not standard where I come from. Where are the people from that use this? What is their demographic? Who do they associate themselves with?

Comment: 'I hiked early this morning with my sister[,] which I am not a morning person!' might be borderline grammatical, but I'd mark it wrong on Orwell VI grounds. Even 'I, which I am not a morning person, hiked early this ... with my sister' would lose a mark. You can legitimise most things with brackets, though even 'I (which I am not a morning person!) hiked early this morning with my sister' would lose a mark on most days. At least the last two attempts put the relative-or-is-it next to the subject it refers to. 'I (and I'm not a morning person!) hiked early this morning with my sister' is fine.

Comment: It _is_ dialectic - every piece of English is one or another. English isn't divided into 'normal' and 'dialect', it's composed of dialects. Queen's English is a dialect as much as Yorkshire. The question is what dialect is this from?

Comment: Which language are they speaking?

Comment: This is a devil of a question, which it is obviously a form of slang but yet usually has a clear(ish) meaning, where, however, how 'which' fits in is hard to explain.  What makes it harder is the fact that I, like others above, can recall hearing this kind of slang use, but cannot find a way of finding wording that might google this use of 'which'.  It does not appear to exist in grammar books.  In your example it is probably explanatory or concessive (which could be seen as sort of counter-explanatory).  I doubt it is 'non-grammatical'.  It is not a 'standard English' usage.

Comment: I can't put a finger on it, but German *wo doch* (wherethough) would fit here. *wo auch* (where also/too) hardly fits, but is pretty close to earlier *whereas*, and I imagine there could be a formal correspondance, though *auch* corresponds to *eke*, not any *-ch*. Indeed, emphatic (concessive?) usage of *why* comes to mind (why, look who's ...), although surely secondary. *which* itself is darn interesting if comparing *-alis*, *-alikos*, I say again and again, though ["whatever size"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Ancient_Greek_correlatives) hardly fits here.

Comment: I'm tripping balls over this it's so weird. Also cp Ger *wahrlich* "indeed, well, truly, very" (understood as *wahr* "true"). That said, I started to think \*-likaz might compare to, say, *logos*, truth be told, I can only guess. I had the idea after considering, like, *length*, *line* for AGr *pelikos* "what size, how big", indeed part of a correlative in Ger. *wo lang* "which way"; cp "to long [for]". BTW, I had doubted *eke* could corresond to *-ch*; the same is assumed for *like* ~ *which* though.

Comment: @vectory Thanks for contributing some intelligent thoughts. I kind of let this fall off my radar after all the comments suggesting it was just a dialectical thing. In the past months I've saved several dozen other examples.

Comment: The answer is simple: The name for the construction is "Wrong". Just because "which" can function as a conjunction does not mean that it will work in all context as a  conjunction. **Which** is basically a pronoun[1] that fronts, or is the subject of, a subordinate (relative) clause. As a pronoun, it must have a substantive as a referent, but your example has no such referent.== [1] it has other functions but these are not relevant.

Comment: @Greybeard I feel pretty confident that it's not grammatical. So I'm looking for a name for the mistake as it seems to be common enough that somebody would have studied it. I appreciate the thoughtful insight.

Comment: the word is "misuse."

Answer (score 2):

I see it as non-grammatical also. I’m more familiar with it as a spoken irregularity than a written one, and have heard it most often when watching youtubers from the southern US states.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let's parse the sentence as "(I hiked early this morning with my sister) (which) (I am not a morning person)!"

The first part is an activity and the last explains its significance.

Looking at it this way, it would be fair to consider the middle part to be intended as a conjunction. Perhaps *when* would have worked better, or if you wanted to preserve more of the original, *whereas*. Using *although* would flow even better, though it takes some of the wind out of the speaker's attempt to sound impressive.

Comment: Your analysis matches up with mine. Do you consider that to be grammatical? I'm not the down vote by the way.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks. I considered der the original to be ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

I've certainly heard it in British NS use and it puzzles me. The use of a relative pronoun implies a degree of linguistic sophistication which is contradicted by the non-standard usage. Is it used as a sign of identity - dialect perhaps? Whatever; it does exist and it is "incorrect".